# Web Api 2 not deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to call a web service API in my application and I am passing in a parameter, but for some reason, its not deserializing the JSON. Instead, its just passing in my JSON as a string. Here is the API code:

```
[Route("api/v1/images/GetMemberImageUrl", Name = "ApiImagesGetMemberImageUrl")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetMemberImageUrl([FromBody]object memberId)
{
    // memberId is a string and it contains "{memberId: 18}"

    // Do stuff
    // ...
}
```

Note that I originally had `[FromBody]int memberId`. I got a bad request, so I changed it to `object` so I could see what exactly was getting passed in. What's getting passed in is a string which contains `"{memberId: 18}"`.

Here is my AJAX call code to the API:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    data: JSON.stringify({memberId: @Infrastructure.Member.GetAuthenticatedMembersId()}),
    url: '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("ApiImagesGetMemberImageUrl", null)',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(retval) {
        // Do more stuff
    }
});
```

Any idea why the model binder is not deserializing my JSON?

Comment: Hey, have you tried to create a model to change from `object` to `YourModel` (that has the same properties from your argument)? Usually I do this way.

Comment: @VagnerLucas - I could probably do that and it might work, however, it's my understanding that the model binder for Web Api 2 is supposed to be smart enough to know how to bind my parameters to the incoming JSON.

Comment: @VagnerLucas - That does work. I just tried it. However, I still think the model binder should do that for me without me having to create a new model class each time.

Comment: @Icemanind diud you try to write just data: {memberId: @Infrastructure.Member.GetAuthenticatedMembersId()}, (without stringify) and add  dataType : "json" parameter?

Comment: Yes. I've got same trouble with this but I think there's no way to bind as long as you're passing a object as argument, and it's getting exactly what you are passing (a json object). I used the `Deserialize` method from `JavaScriptSerializer` and it was an approach.

Comment: @Icemanind I just googled and found this: [posting-raw-json-to-web-api](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api). Take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your model like

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

Or post your data as simple value without defining JSON object `{memberId: 18}`. Simply like

```
"18"
```

Then it will be mapped to your property memberId, even if property will have another name.

More [reading](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)